# Can I make alias for alias in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line, alias

In some circumstances, I need to make an official alias for a set of command, which acts just the same as the original software. Like:

```
alias ipython3="source /Users/zen1/miniconda2/bin/activate py3k; ipython; source /Users/zen1/miniconda2/bin/deactivate;"
```

But as I was lazy, I'd like to use another alias for alias `ipython3`, let it be `ipy3`, I could do it by just copying `ipython3`'s content. But that would be too clumsy.

Is there some magic_func so that `alias ipy3=magic_func("ipython3")` can get the alias content of `ipython3` when using `ipy3`?

---

PS:
`ipython3` should be kept is because it is the official command to trigger `ipython for python 3`, which can't be installed properly on my computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
alias ipy3='ipython3'
```

Comment: Wow, this means alias for alias is internally support by bash? Never thought about it. As ipy3 is under ipython3, it will works, right?

Comment: Yes, it will work.

Comment: @Zen You can even control that: `alias ipy3='"ipython3"'` would not try a second level alias replacement; using `"ipy3"` instead of "`ipy3` would avaoid the first level replacement. Furthermore you can use aliases for parameters if the earlier alias value ends with a space: `alias ech="echo foo "; alias text="bar baz"; ech text`